# how to draw UIBezierPaths swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

[image]

Here's what I want to do:

with help `UIBezierPath` i want draw mask like on this link

```
// Create an image context containing the original UIImage.
let maskWithHole = CAShapeLayer()
let biggerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: withSize.width, height: withSize.height)
let maskPath = UIBezierPath() //UIBezierPath(roundedRect: toRectArray.first!, cornerRadius: 40)

maskPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: biggerRect.minX, y: biggerRect.minY))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: biggerRect.minX, y: biggerRect.maxY))

maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: biggerRect.maxX, y: biggerRect.maxY))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: biggerRect.maxX, y: biggerRect.minY))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: biggerRect.minX, y: biggerRect.minY))

let smallerRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: withSize.width - 10, height: withSize.height - 10)

maskPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: smallerRect.minX, y: smallerRect.minY))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: smallerRect.minX, y: smallerRect.maxY))

maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: smallerRect.maxX, y: smallerRect.maxY))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: smallerRect.maxX, y: smallerRect.minY))
maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: smallerRect.minX, y: smallerRect.minY))
maskWithHole.path = maskPath.cgPath
maskWithHole.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
maskWithHole.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
maskWithHole.opacity = 1.0
```

it's work i cut inside content of image but want round rect inside when cut like link image.

Comment: I don't see any _mask_ on the image – that is a winter forest.

Comment: mask is black image over winter forest.

Comment: Just a question, why you don't use imageView.layer.cornerRadius and a black background view to get the same result?